# How to increase Data Catalog payload limit in AWS Glue service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I wrote down a Glue `job` to start a crawler for a set of dynamo DB tables. Each table weighs around 100GB. The crawler successfully executes and creates a table within the Glue Catalog as long as the referred dynamo table is less than 1GB. For bigger tables, I've tracked down the following message on the cloud trail history.

```json
{
    "eventVersion": "1.08",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "AssumedRole",
        "principalId": "AROA6DWCE2WUEUUOLNVTJ:AWS-Crawler",
    ...
    ...
    ...
    "eventTime": "2021-10-25T18:56:51Z",
    "eventSource": "glue.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "CreateTable",
    "awsRegion": "us-west-2",
    "sourceIPAddress": "glue.amazonaws.com",
    "userAgent": "glue.amazonaws.com",
    "errorCode": "InvalidInputException",
    "errorMessage": "Payload size of request exceeded limit",
    ...
    ...
    ...
    "eventCategory": "Management"
}
```

Any clue what might be happening here?

Comment: The table size (1gb, 10gb, 100gb, 1tb, ....) should have nothing to do with the CreateTable operation since a glue table does not contain the data but only the metadata which should be a few kb max (not counting partitions, and table versions, they consume a lot of space). Is the schema of the table so big? Maybe the crawler tries to infer a lot of useless type information and exceeds the actual metadata limit of a few MB!?

Comment: @luk2302 do you think that this may be caused by a high number of fields (i.e. more than 5k) within JSON schema?

Comment: Yes, that is most likely the issue.